# Terminology: angular frequency vs frequency

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation, terminology

I am confused about the usage of the terms frequency and angular frequency in physics texts. E.g. in the book "Classical Electrodynamics" of J.D. Jackson, one considers in formula (7.3) page 296, plane wave solutions to the Helmholtz equation of the form

$u(x,t) = e^{ i kx-i\omega t }$

where $\omega$ is refereed to as the frequency. Why is this not called the angular frequency? Is this a common abbreviation in physics, or something to do with units, or what?

Comment: The convention is that $\omega$ always means angular frequency and $f$ or $\nu$ means (linear) frequency. $\omega$ is always being used in so many different places that it is a mouthful to keep calling it angular frequency, and so people just call it frequency. Just be aware that this is a thing and you always have to resort to looking at the symbol they are using to make sure what is being meant.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. So is it a well known practice in physics to call the angular frequency, just  frequency? In the Jackson book there seems to be no mention of of the term "angular frequency" in the context of plane waves.

Comment: That is precisely what I have said. It is the same silliness as calling the Lagrangian density as just Lagrangian, and so many other similar potentially dangerous short forms. Always seek clarification and comparison to make sure that factors of 2 and $2\pi$ are not missing. If in a computation you miss a $\hslash$ or $k_B$, the huge discrepancy makes it possible for us to deduce that we made a mistake. Factors of 2 and $2\pi$ cannot be caught that way and will always be a pain if we are not careful about them.

Comment: Ok, thanks. That is good to know!